# jqGrid displays only one record all the time, Why?

Tags: jqgrid, rows

I am facing this issue where my server returns 3 records, but the grid alwas shows only the first record, irrespective of the number of the records. Here is my grid configuration.

```
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    autowidth: true,
    autoheight: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,

    datatype: 'local',
    viewrecords: true,
    hidegrid: false,

    colModel: [...],

    rowNum: -1,        
    recreateForm: true
});

$('#grid').setGridParam({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: [ {...}, {...} ]
}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `rowNum: -1` have **wrong value**. If you need show all records without paging you should use some large *positive* value like `rowNum: 10000`. The second problem is setting of `data` parameter with respect of `setGridParam`. You should first remove old data and then set new one.

Comment: Hi Oleg, actually I have borrowed working piece of code (one shown in the question) from another module in my project. They have used rowNum: -1 there, and it is working well. I am using jqGrid v4.5.4. Has something related to rowNum changed? Second, you mean I should clear the grid rows before reload?

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: The setting could work only if you use `datatype: "json"` (or `datatype: "xml"`) and not use `loadonce: true` and if your server can interpret input parameter `rows=-1`. Because it was allowed setting is some very old versions the corresponding part in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) (see description of `rowNum`) was crossed instead of removing. By the way I suggest you to add `rownumbers: true` option and see the results in case of usage wrong value `rowNum: -1`. Do you tried my suggestion? Is your problem solved?

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg, it worked! Either I should have rowNum: 10000 or not have it at all. I prefer not to specify it. And the rownumbers is awesome.

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: If you not specify `rowNum` then default value 20 will be used (see "Default" column in the table with options in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)). In the case only the first 20 rows will be shown. If the grid has no pager the user have no way to see other rows. Is it what you want?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have added rowNum back. And I have one more problem. Lets say I have 6 columns, the columns do not span to the entire width of the grid, there is a space (like for an empty column) after the last column. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: I personally prefer to use `height: "auto"` option which fix the problem too. Alternatively you can use `scrollOffset: 0` which remove 18 pixel on the right side reserved per default for vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. I got it working. Haven't tried the scrollOffset yet but get on to it later.